# How to convert absolute time to local time?

Tags: date-and-time

I tried this code:

```
ubt = WeatherData["Ulaanbaatar", 
  "Temperature" , {{2006, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {2006, 1, 2, 0, 0}}, 
  TimeZone -> +8];

shifted = TimeSeriesShift[ubt, Quantity[8, "Hour"]];
Export["UbShift2.txt", shifted]
```

My result is

[image]

first colums information is date and time. How to convert this absulute time to local time . For example 2015 6 1 3 0 0. Help me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateList` or `DateString`, depending on desired output:

```
DateList[3345091200]

(* {2006, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0.} *)


DateString[3345091200]

(* "Sun 1 Jan 2006 08:00:00" *)
```

**Edit:** to use this in your specific example, you could do something like this:

```
Export["UbShift2.txt", Append[DateList[#[[1]]], QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]] & /@ shifted["Path"]]
```

Comment: how remove dot. `(* {2006, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0.} *)`

Comment: I try `DateList[{#[[1]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ shifted`. not successfull